# Where can i get the MySQL Sonarqube download

Tags: mysql, database, download, sonarqube

I am trying to install Sonarqube 6.4 (On a Mac with MySQL).  Downloaded from the official web site and going through the [instructions](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Installing+the+Server) I am stuck on the first step!  where can i get the database schema from?  There are links on the web but they are pointing to sites which not longer exist.  Is it in the official download?  Or anywhere else on the official site?  I must be doing something stupid i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database schema will be created upon SonarQube startup, so you don't need to download any script to create the schema.

Comment: You do actually need to create an _empty_ schema. The first startup will populate it with tables, indices, ...